# wiring from car amplifier to leds syncing to bass

Tags: led, audio, music

I have 12 V batteries, 2 1500-watt amps and 2 Ω each, and 2 subwoofers at 2 Ω each.

I was planning on buying 4 blue 12 V led light strips that run at about 100mA each. I would like it to brighten/dim depending on how hard the bass hits.

If I were to hook 2 up to one amp, and 2 to the other, what kind of driver would I need?

Comment: You want a low-pass filter, and a switching mechanism. Ideally taken from the unamplified source so the volume setting doesn't affect the response.

Comment: @Majenko, you might be right about the volume setting.

Comment: The amplifier has a low pass filter on it. How would I go about hooking the led strips to the Low pass filter?

Can you explain more on this? 

From what I understand, you think I should put a low pass filter on the unamplified source (signal wire aka rca inputs?), then hook the leds to that with a switch?

Comment: Yes, but by "switch" I mean transistor based saturation amplifier (threshold voltage for full on/off).  The LEDs then draw their power direct from the battery through the final stage transistor.  An op-amp used as a comparator would make a good first stage saturation amplifier, which then drives a MOSFET for doing the actual power switching. You could even then use a pot for setting the threshold voltage to trigger the LEDs on to change the sensitivity.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I'm a bit out of my element here, but may I suggest a simple experiment? And others please offer your comments about if anything is going to blow up here.

So from what I can calculate from the values given to me (and please forgive me that I am not a PA Hi-Fi expert so I don't have clear ideas about the statistical distributions of bass signals) It would seem that if you have 1500W max power to a 2 ohm load, ohm's law says that you would have a 54 volt max RMS voltage. For pure Sine, the maximum voltage is something like 60V, but we're not dealing with pure sines here.

Ok. Looking from the other direction, if you connect four 12V LED strips in series (the plus of first is your PLUS, and the minus from first goes to plus of the next and the minus of the next goes to the plus of the one after that and finally the minus of the last strip is the MINUS of the whole lot), then the rated forward voltage of that combined strip would be 48 volts.

What I propose is a very simple experiment. Connect the four strips in parallel and then connect it directly to the amplifier outputs, in parallel with one of the subwoofers. Don't worry about connecting it backwards, the backward current will not break the strip (http://www.nteinc.com/LED_tubing/led_strip_faqs.php).

Then *carefully* switch on the amplifier, making sure that there is no music playing at the source and the volume is at zero. Start playing something and *gently* bring up the volume. See what happens and report back here. Do you see any light at all or is it too bright? If it's too bright, then it might also become too hot in time, and heat is what kills the LEDs. And as the whole thing is connected in series, when the first LED dies, all the others will go black too.

Now, please concerns and criticism from others. Do you see it affecting the sound output? I can envision *some* distortion on the sound but probably nothing you could hear in a car. How about the safety? Do you see this thing blowing up or damaging other equipment? And yes, the brightness of the LEDs would be somewhat directly related to the volume in this very simple connection. The question is what happens at some suitable volume level.

Comment: First of all, the amps are going to be 1500w rms, not max power. Secondly, I haven't ordered the LED strips yet, but from my experience plugging them directly into the amp is going to be way to much power going to the led's. The Led's are going to use around 400 MA total, or .4 amps. The amplifier itself is putting out around 100-130 amps if my calculations are correct.

Comment: @onion21 it very much depends on the voltage rating of the led strips. My guess is that they will need more than 12V, so you need to supply them separately, also to not disturb the audio signal.